# What is the difference between a regular path and a piecewise regular path?

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis

[image]

In my textbook, I have the above two definitions. However, I don't understand the difference between them. I mean, is there a regular path that is not piecewise regular and vice versa?
If we look at this proposition. Would the proof still work if $\gamma$ was just regular?

[image]

Comment: A regular path is also piecewise regular (e.g. with just one piece) . A piecewise regular path need not be regular because it need not have a (double-sided) derivative at the points where the pieces join.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis, I think it does take the left-sided derivative at $b_j$ and  right-sided derivative at  $a_{j+1}$

Comment: Yes, but their values need not be the same, so the path does not always have an ordinary derivative there. So a piecewise regular path is like a regular one but with a finite number of troublesome points where there is no well-defined derivative.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis, Does this mean that if $\gamma$ is piecewise regular in $[a,b]$, then it is not necessarily continuous on $[a,b]$? or just that $\gamma^\prime$ not continuous in $[a,b]$?

Comment: Just that $\gamma^\prime$ is not necessarily continuous. So $\gamma$ is continuous (the regular pieces join up at their end points), but not necessarily what is called "smooth" (there may be kinks at the join points).